# Absolute URL are messing with ng-src

Tags: angularjs

So, I already used `ng-src` directive but never with absolute images URL. Now that I am, I'm having issues. It seems like Angular tries to evaluate the URL as an expression which does not make any sense to me.

Here is the tag:

```
<img ng-src="{{message.logo_url}}" ng-show="{{message.logo_url}}">
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/2/000/0ad/2dd/0511c49.png] starting at [://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/2/000/0ad/2dd/0511c49.png].
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at throwError (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6671:11)
    at parser (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6663:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7281:29
    at compileToFn (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9214:16)
    at Object.Scope.$watch (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8546:19)
    at http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15580:11
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4959:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4550:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/customer/service/gui/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4553:13) <img ng-src="{{message.logo_url}}" ng-show="{{message.logo_url}}"> angular.js:6349
(anonymous function) angular.js:6349
(anonymous function) angular.js:5420
nodeLinkFn angular.js:4962
compositeLinkFn angular.js:4550
compositeLinkFn angular.js:4553
compositeLinkFn angular.js:4553
publicLinkFn angular.js:4455
ngRepeatAction angular.js:15462
$watchCollectionAction angular.js:8717
Scope.$digest angular.js:8811
Scope.$apply angular.js:9012
done angular.js:10265
completeRequest angular.js:10449
xhr.onreadystatechange angular.js:10404
```

If you need anything more, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<img ng-src="{{message.logo_url}}" ng-show="message.logo_url">
```

as stated in [`ngShow`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)'s documentation.

Comment: Ahah! Thanks for your time! I needed an external point of view. I was completely focusing on the wrong directive. Thanks!